# Load user by specific role

Tags: users, user-roles

I need to load only the subscribers

```
$args = array('role' => 'Subscriber');
$subscribers = get_users($args);
```

but with this, it returns also the users that are subscriber AND other role (I need to delete my subscribers only, but keep subscribers with other role)

How do I get this users ?

Comment: You mean, you have users who have two or more roles like `user1` having the roles `subscriber` *and* `custom_role`?

Comment: Yes, `user1` is `subscriber` and `user2` is `subscriber + manager`, I need to get only `user1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is by using the `role__not_in` parameter like so which excludes all other roles except `subscriber`:

```php
// Include only the following role(s):
$roles_in = array( 'subscriber' );

$roles_not_in = array_diff(
    array_keys( wp_roles()->get_names() ),
    $roles_in
);

$args = array(
    'role__not_in' => $roles_not_in,
);

$subscribers = get_users( $args );
```

But of course, if you know the exact roles that should be excluded, then just do `'role__not_in' => array( 'role', 'role2', 'etc' )`.

Comment: Thanks, I've ended up doing the second way